# How to get the request header in a Dart Aqueduct server

Tags: dart, http-headers, httprequest, aqueduct

I want to get a token from the `Authorization` header of the request.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:aqueduct/aqueduct.dart';


class SecretController extends ResourceController {

  @Operation.get()
  Future<Response> signin() async {

    request.headers // ??? not available

  }
}
```

How do I access that header in [Aqueduct](https://aqueduct.io/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A request is a wrapper around a raw HttpRequest object from the Dart standard library, so one way is to access it like this:

```
request.raw.headers["authorization"]
```

You can also bind the value of a header to a method parameter; this is nice when you want to parse the string header value into another type and/or validate the header. ([You can do some really convenient stuff with binding.](https://aqueduct.io/docs/http/resource_controller/))

```
@Operation.get()
Future<Response> signIn(
  @Bind.header("authorization") String authorization) async {
  ...
}
```

Finally, specific to the Authorization header, you can use Authorizer middleware. This validates the authorization header and creates an Authorization object with the details of authorized resource owner ('the user') that you can access from your method.

```
router.route("/secret")
  .link(() => Authorizer.bearer(authServer))
  .link(() => SecretController());

...

@Operation.get()
Future<Response> signIn() async {
  final userIDForRequest = request.authorization.ownerID;
}
```